# UITextChecker for Set of Strings - Swift 4.2

Tags: string, set, swift4.2, uitextchecker

I currently have this `Extension` thanks to @Leo Dabus. It works perfectly for a single `String`, but how would I implement this same logic to an `Set` of `Strings` like `var mySet = ["word", "notaword", "stillnotaword"]`. In this example, I would want the function to only identify the first `index` as `true` (i.e. an English word).

```
extension String {
    public mutating func isEnglishWord() -> Bool {
        return UITextChecker().rangeOfMisspelledWord(in: self, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: utf16.count), startingAt: 0, wrap: false, language: "en_US").location == NSNotFound
    }
}

var myString = "word"

myString.isEnglishWord()
```

Comment: You can loop through the array and call the function on every value. Is this what you want?

Comment: Preferably, the function would print only the valid English words or perhaps identify the index location of only the valid English words.

Comment: @Ehsan  I have too many values for that to work.

Comment: You have to loop through each value to check. Thats the most straight forward solution. You can improve it further once you do the simple solution.

Comment: I could use .forEach to loop through the Set. But, I don’t know how to implement UITextChecker for each value within the loop. Nor, can I figure how to properly enumerate or identify each value or index during the loop. Any more suggestions or any resources would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Let me add the answer. Test and let me know if it works to your expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let words = ["word", "notaword", "stillnotaword"]

let validWords = words.filter { word -> Bool in
    return word.isEnglishWord()
}

let wordsArray : NSArray = NSArray(array: words)
let validWordsIndexes = wordsArray.indexesOfObjects { (word, index, _) -> Bool in
    return (word as! String).isEnglishWord()
}

print(validWords)
print(validWordsIndexes)

extension String {
    public func isEnglishWord() -> Bool {
        return UITextChecker().rangeOfMisspelledWord(in: self, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: utf16.count), startingAt: 0, wrap: false, language: "en_US").location == NSNotFound
    }
}
```

I have added the code to print valid words and indexes of valid words. You can choose which ever suits you. Thanks

Comment: @Ehsan  Thanks for the answer. It looks good, but I can't test it b/c Xcode keeps quitting unexpectedly for no reason. Once I figure what's wrong with Xcode and I get it running properly, then I will test your code and Accept as long as it works.

Comment: It kind of works. It's printing properly for identifying the valid English words. But the print for the index does not identify the index. Rather, it counts the number of times a valid English word occurs. I'm not worried about the index aspect because the print for identifying the valid English words does the trick for me. However, Xcode Playgrounds is showing me 2 errors. Both say **Value of type 'String' has no member 'isEnglishWord'**  Are you getting those errors?

Comment: As the array is a generic type. You have to type cast it to String than call the isEnglishWord. As done in my answer. A

Comment: @Ehsan  Ever since I updated my Mac with a couple Apple recommended updates, my Xcode Playground has been totally bugging out. Using your exact code, Playground is printing the proper output. But, it also shows the errors stated above.  **When you run your code in Playgrounds, are you getting those errors too?** If not, then the problem is just another Xcode glitch.

Comment: perhaps its the xcode glitch. Because the same code compiles and runs absolutely fine on my xcode.

Comment: I'll take your word for it until I can figure out how to fix my Xcode Playground. In addition to those errors, it's constantly quitting unexpectedly. Thanks for the answer.